# No password input after locking the device from Android Device Manager

Tags: lock-screens, android-device-manager, password-protection

I have forgotten my unlock pattern and tried to lock my device with a password on Android Device Manager (ADM). It did lock and a message, "Your device is locked by Android Device Manager" appears, but there's no way of entering a password on that screen.

[image]

There's no password field, and just a back click and it's all gone. Pressing​ that lock icon doesn't work, it's not a button, neither sliding up or down, left or right is any good.

How to unlock it?